# Remove debug messages in the console (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, logging

I was randomly modifying properties in my nodejs environement and a few days later discovered that I was getting a huuuge amount of debug logs in my console. This is a bit annoying and I don't know how to disable this.

What kind of debug messages I'm getting:

```sh
  express:application set "jsonp callback name" to 'callback' +0ms
  express:router:route new '/' +74ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +1ms
  express:router:route get '/' +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +1ms
  express:router:route new '/redirect' +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/redirect' +1ms
  express:router:route get '/redirect' +11ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router:route new '/logout' +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/logout' +1ms
  express:router:route get '/logout' +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:application set "view engine" to 'ejs' +4ms

follow-redirects options {
  maxRedirects: 21,
  maxBodyLength: 10485760,
  protocol: 'https:',
  path: '/api/token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    Authorization: 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=',
    'User-Agent': 'axios/0.20.0',
    'Content-Length': 29
  },
  agent: undefined,
  agents: { http: undefined, https: undefined },
  auth: undefined,
  hostname: 'accounts.spotify.com',

mquery findOne guildmembers { id: '699912716474777631', guildID: '730132810458857483' } { projection: {} } +19ms
  mquery findOne users { id: '699912716474777631' } { projection: {} } +6ms
  mquery findOne guilds { id: '730132810458857483' } { projection: {} } +3ms
```

Could anyone help me to disable this ?
Thanks in advance !

(I am on Windows 10)

Comment: Have you tried running with `NODE_ENV=production`

Comment: I've tried to enter `set NODE_ENV=production` but nothing changes...

Comment: I think you enabled the debug that's why you get this type of debug logging may be this will help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug